# Mariadb default logs location & --log-error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf, log

I am using mariadb and I to investigate some issue I wanted to check the logs. To my surprise, log file is not generated for mariadb.

I suspect this cannot be the case so I am doubting my search skills.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like 'log_error'
    -> ;
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_error     |       |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have added the entry in my.cnf still above field is coming to be empty.

```
[root@cslcodev11-oem ~]# cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
!includedir /etc/mysqld/conf.d
datadir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/mnt/mgmt/var/lib/mysql_tmp
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
### TRT-3229 #####
sync_binlog=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_support_xa = 1
myisam_repair_threads = 2
myisam_recover_options = FORCE
###################
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
table_open_cache=256
max_heap_table_size=256M
### TRT-4685 ###
max_connections=500
################
innodb_log_file_size = 512M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
[root@cslcodev11-oem ~]#
```

So, I want to know do we have any default location where these logs are getting generated, if the path cannot be read from config files.

### Update:

After some investigation, I found this information,

*Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/error-log/*

---

**Activating the Error Log**

The error log is active by default. The log-error=filename option determines where the output will be written. If no file name is specified, the log will be written to host-name.err. If no absolute path is specified, the file will be written to the data directory (determined by the value of the datadir system variable).

*On Unix systems, if the --log-error option is not used, the errors are written to stderr (usually, the command line).*

*On Windows, if the --console option is specified, and --log-error is not used, the errors are written to the console. If --log-error is present, --console is ignored.*

So now I understand that due to some reason the configuration **log_error** in my.cnf is not considered.  So as per the suggestion, on Unix system, if --log-error is not used, logs are redirected to stdout.

---

BUT, I am starting the service using `service mysqld start` command so I want to know what all options are used by default when we start the service using `service mysql start`? ESP, is --log-error used?

Answer (score 2):

Going off the documentation, the error log should be in the default location of `/var/lib/mysql` and it should be named the default `hostname.err`, but it's just not there.

In the directory `/var/lib/mysql` I do have a `tc.log`, `iblogfile0`, `iblogfile1`, `aria_log.00000001`, and `aria_log_control` files. But I cannot read any of them, they are encrypted. Anyone know what these are?

> BUT, I am starting the service using service mysqld start command so I want to know what all options are used by default when we start the service using service mysql start? ESP, is --log-error used?

After running the following command,

`cat /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service | grep "mysql"`

we can see that the line that systemd uses to start the process is `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION`. The options passed to MariaDB are stored in the `$MYSQLD_OPTS` variable.

If we also run `cat /etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service | grep "MYSQLD_OPTS"` we get the following.

```
MYSQLD_OPTS here is for users to set in /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/MY_SPECIAL.conf
Use the [Service] section and Environment="MYSQLD_OPTS=...".
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION
```

The file MY_SPECIAL.conf does not exist on my machine, as `find / -name "*MY_SPECIAL*"` reveals.

I do have entries for `mysqld` in `journalctl`. So I'm thinking that it uses the the `systemd` system logs by default for us `systemd` users.

On the [MariaDB Knowledge base page for the error-log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/error-log/) there is a paragraph that states.

> `systemd` has its own logging system, and Linux distributions running `systemd` may log errors there instead. To view the systemd logs, use `journalctl -u mariadb`.

This answers the question because `--log-error` would be an option that could be added to `MY_SPECIAL.conf` file and `journalctl` is where mariadb logs errors by default on a `systemd` system.

Answer (score 0):

`log-error` or `log_error`?

`log-error` is the correct name to assign to when setting options in the options file `my.cnf`.

`log_error` is the correct system variable name when reading like `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%error%'`.

Reference links: [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/system-variables/server-system-variables/#log) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-option-tables.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using systemd, then I think the reason why you're not seeing the error log at `/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log` as specified in your `my.cnf` might be that you have put `log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mysqld.log` in the wrong option group - [mysqld_safe] is not used when you're using systemd. You could move it to e.g. the [mysqld] section instead, which should work.

Also, make sure you don't have `skip-log-error` anywhere in your .cnf files - you better check the included .cnf files as well, as you have `!includedir /etc/mysqld/conf.d`.

Answer (score -5):

the variable name for log path is log_error but you have set log-error in your my.cnf and therefore the logs are not generated. if you correct it in your my.cnf to log_error, it should work.

Comment: False. This is simply not true.